# Camera Full Preview stops display

Tags: hdmi, camera, raspicam

Using `raspistill -fp -o test.jpg` causes my monitor (actually a tv) to receive no input (just get a blue screen) for the duration of the preview. This also happens using the python `picamera` module with the max resolution.

I'm semi certain that I had this working before on the same setup but I'm not sure what, if anything, I've changed.

I've tried playing around with a few of the settings in `/boot/config.txt` but not totally sure what changes to make.

Any thoughts?